# Unable to download OS X Mojave

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

OS X Mojave has to be downloaded from App store, but I have tried multiple times and failed. Every time it reaches **6.02 GB** (complete download), App store reports an error has occurred. I have updated my Mac before and non of these problems occurred. Other applications are also able to download. I am working beside the wireless router, and the connection seems to be stable throughout. All internet services are usable. Why would this happen? Is there anything I can do to fix it, or is it a problem with App store or apple's servers?

Comment: How much free space do you have on the disk you're downloading to?

Comment: 355.3 GB. I think that should be enough.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. It may not be the faster option, but if you live near an Apple Store, you can upgrade your Mac there, see https://www.apple.com/macos/how-to-upgrade/.

Comment: Apparently I just had to try one more time. Thanks anyways,